# Find a value anywhere in a database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given a number, how do I discover in what table and column it could be found within?

I don't care if it's fast, it just needs to work.

Comment: You want to search all columns/rows for a particular number? Can you restrict it to numeric columns? Integer columns? Identity columns?

Comment: all columns would be best, but numeric would do.  Indentity Columns are too specific

Comment: You probably have to write a short script to query the metadata (in this case a list of tables/columns) from the database, and issue a series of select statements looking for the value.

Comment: This is ancient, but why not just do a dump and grep the dump?

Comment: phpmyadmin allow this very simply

Answer (score 347, accepted):

[This might help you](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm). - from Narayana Vyas. It searches all columns of all tables in a given database. I have used it before and it works.

This is the Stored Proc from the above link - the only change I made was substituting the temp table for a table variable so you don't have to remember to drop it each time.

```
CREATE PROC SearchAllTables
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

-- Copyright © 2002 Narayana Vyas Kondreddi. All rights reserved.
-- Purpose: To search all columns of all tables for a given search string
-- Written by: Narayana Vyas Kondreddi
-- Site: http://vyaskn.tripod.com
-- Tested on: SQL Server 7.0 and SQL Server 2000
-- Date modified: 28th July 2002 22:50 GMT

DECLARE @Results TABLE(ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + 
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END 
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM @Results
END
```

To execute the stored procedure :

```
 EXEC SearchAllTables 'YourStringHere'
```

Comment: FYI this script only searches text fields, not number fields.  In my case it worked because the devs were storing a number in a varchar, but generally finding numbers won't work.

Comment: Can we do this using a single query instead of using a stored procedure?

Comment: The only drawback here is that it would be more efficient if all columns of each table were checked at once (to avoid multiple reads on the same data pages). Again, I think it would be easy to make this optimization on the script above (I already did something similar, some time ago).

Comment: What if we want the column to contain two search strings? I mean all the columns containing two strings in different rows.

Comment: Is there any chance someone knows how mo migrate this to snowflake (which uses javascript language inside). Would be beyond awesome

Comment: where should I change the database name?

Comment: where do I set the database name?

Answer (score 81):

If you need to run such search only once then you can probably go with any of the scripts already shown in other answers. But otherwise, I’d recommend using [ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) for this. It’s a free SSMS addin and it really saved me a lot of time.

Before running any of the scripts you should customize it based on the data type you want to search. If you know you are searching for datetime column then there is no need to search through nvarchar columns. This will speed up all of the queries above.

Comment: took me a while to figure out where to do this, anyone reading this comment it can be done in the query by altering this piece from the accepted answer: AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')

Comment: Also note that while ApexSQL makes you pay for some of their tools, this one is free of charge. You just have to give them your email. A great tool, this is gonna help me so much when digging in undocumented 3rd party databases :)

Comment: This should be the top answer, IMHO.  The ability to filter on different datatypes is great.  The only gripe I have about it, is that the GUI for selecting/de-selecting "what tables to search in" is a checkbox-list with **NO** check/uncheck-ALL option or multi-select-and-toggle ability.  So if you want to, say, un-check all the system objects (which are ​*checked* by default, which is silly), you have to go thru a space-arrowdown-space-arrowdown ​*ad-nauseum* exercise.  But thankfully, it's efficient enough that you ​don't have to​.  Just let it search & do its thing!

Comment: ApexSQL Search is definitely the best solution. I just tried using the script to find an email addres in a database - 8:30 minutes later, I gave up. After installing ApexSQL Search, I searched for exactly the same string, and it found it 31 times in 11 tables. I didn't time it accurately, but it took less than a minute

Answer (score 79):

Based on bnkdev's answer I modified [Narayana's Code](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm) to search all columns even numeric ones.

It'll run slower, but this version actually finds all matches not just those found in text columns.

I can't thank this guy enough. Saved me days of searching by hand!

```
CREATE PROC SearchAllTables 
(
@SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

-- Copyright © 2002 Narayana Vyas Kondreddi. All rights reserved.
-- Purpose: To search all columns of all tables for a given search string
-- Written by: Narayana Vyas Kondreddi
-- Site: http://vyaskn.tripod.com
-- Tested on: SQL Server 7.0 and SQL Server 2000
-- Date modified: 28th July 2002 22:50 GMT


CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)                  
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(max), ' + @ColumnName + '), 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE CONVERT(varchar(max), ' + @ColumnName + ') LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END 
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
END
```

Comment: edited to address the "Insufficient result space to convert uniqueidentifier value to char" error. This will now also work for XML columns.

Comment: here's a new one: Explicit conversion from data type image to varchar(max) is not allowed. I am going to try and fix this on my own, but if someone beats me to it let me know, thanks!

Comment: Ok, i just added back a piece from kd7's code to only search for the data types im looking for which would leave those image columns out of my search causing the error to disappear... AND DATA_TYPE NOT IN ('image')

Comment: Getting "Conversion of one or more characters from XML to target collation impossible  error" in SQL server 2014.

Comment: You could just have different versions for different variable types.  That way you're not casting and it will run quicker.  You could also compare the file types to search cast-able types.  An integer could be in a varchar field.

Comment: Where in the script should I place the string that I want to find? in set @SearchStr2?

Comment: This is amazing.

Answer (score 44):

This is my independent take on this question that I use for my own work.  It works in SQL2000 and greater, allows wildcards, column filtering, and will search most of the normal data types.

A pseudo-code description could be `select * from * where any like 'foo'`

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Search all columns in all tables in a database for a string.
-- Does not search: image, sql_variant or user-defined types.
-- Exact search always for money and smallmoney; no wildcards for matching these.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @SearchTerm nvarchar(4000) -- Can be max for SQL2005+
declare @ColumnName sysname

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- SET THESE!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set @SearchTerm = N'foo' -- Term to be searched for, wildcards okay
set @ColumnName = N'' -- Use to restrict the search to certain columns, wildcards okay, null or empty string for all cols
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END SET
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

set nocount on

declare @TabCols table (
      id int not null primary key identity
    , table_schema sysname not null
    , table_name sysname not null
    , column_name sysname not null
    , data_type sysname not null
)
insert into @TabCols (table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type)
    select t.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, c.DATA_TYPE
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c on t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA
            and t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
    where 1 = 1
        and t.TABLE_TYPE = 'base table'
        and c.DATA_TYPE not in ('image', 'sql_variant')
        and c.COLUMN_NAME like case when len(@ColumnName) > 0 then @ColumnName else '%' end
    order by c.TABLE_NAME, c.ORDINAL_POSITION

declare
      @table_schema sysname
    , @table_name sysname
    , @column_name sysname
    , @data_type sysname
    , @exists nvarchar(4000) -- Can be max for SQL2005+
    , @sql nvarchar(4000) -- Can be max for SQL2005+
    , @where nvarchar(4000) -- Can be max for SQL2005+
    , @run nvarchar(4000) -- Can be max for SQL2005+

while exists (select null from @TabCols) begin

    select top 1
          @table_schema = table_schema
        , @table_name = table_name
        , @exists = 'select null from [' + table_schema + '].[' + table_name + '] where 1 = 0'
        , @sql = 'select ''' + '[' + table_schema + '].[' + table_name + ']' + ''' as TABLE_NAME, * from [' + table_schema + '].[' + table_name + '] where 1 = 0'
        , @where = ''
    from @TabCols
    order by id

    while exists (select null from @TabCols where table_schema = @table_schema and table_name = @table_name) begin

        select top 1
              @column_name = column_name
            , @data_type = data_type
        from @TabCols
        where table_schema = @table_schema
            and table_name = @table_name
        order by id

        -- Special case for money
        if @data_type in ('money', 'smallmoney') begin
            if isnumeric(@SearchTerm) = 1 begin
                set @where = @where + ' or [' + @column_name + '] = cast(''' + @SearchTerm + ''' as ' + @data_type + ')' -- could also cast the column as varchar for wildcards
            end
        end
        -- Special case for xml
        else if @data_type = 'xml' begin
            set @where = @where + ' or cast([' + @column_name + '] as nvarchar(max)) like ''' + @SearchTerm + ''''
        end
        -- Special case for date
        else if @data_type in ('date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'smalldatetime', 'time') begin
            set @where = @where + ' or convert(nvarchar(50), [' + @column_name + '], 121) like ''' + @SearchTerm + ''''
        end
        -- Search all other types
        else begin
            set @where = @where + ' or [' + @column_name + '] like ''' + @SearchTerm + ''''
        end

        delete from @TabCols where table_schema = @table_schema and table_name = @table_name and column_name = @column_name

    end

    set @run = 'if exists(' + @exists + @where + ') begin ' + @sql + @where + ' print ''' + @table_name + ''' end'
    print @run
    exec sp_executesql @run

end

set nocount off
```

I don't put it in proc form since I don't want to maintain it across hundreds of DBs and it's really for ad-hoc work anyway.  Please feel free to comment on bug-fixes.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting nothing but syntax errors on this in phpMyAdmin. Has something changed with SQL since this was written?

Comment: @NoBugs This is written in T-SQL for SQL Server.

Comment: @NoBugs: You need to encapsulate the code inside your own stored procedure or some other function.

Comment: What exactly is the @SearchTerm for if we're already passing in the search string in the parameter? Thx

Comment: @Fernando68 have you made a proc out of this? The ad-hoc batch in my answer doesn't have parameters.

Comment: Just to clarify the output, if running this from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, the Results tab will only pop open if the search term is found. If the search term is not found, only the Messages tab will open with the executed search statements. The Message tab does not include any results but will also open along with the Results tab when the search term is found.

Comment: Very straight forward approach, thanks a lot man

Answer (score 23):

I optimized Allain Lalonde answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/436676/412368).
Numeric values are still supported. Should be roughly 4-5 times faster (1:03 vs 4:30), tested on a desktop with a 7GB database. http://developer.azurewebsites.net/2015/01/mssql-searchalltables/

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.SearchAllTables', 'P') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.SearchAllTables;
GO

CREATE PROC SearchAllTables 
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

-- Copyright © 2002 Narayana Vyas Kondreddi. All rights reserved.
-- Purpose: To search all columns of all tables for a given search string
-- Written by: Narayana Vyas Kondreddi
-- Site: http://vyaskn.tripod.com
-- Customized and modified: 2014-01-21
-- Tested on: SQL Server 2008 R2

DECLARE @Results TABLE(ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256)
DECLARE @ColumnName nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @DataType nvarchar(128)

DECLARE @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
DECLARE @SearchDecimal decimal(38,19)
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(4000)
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%', '''')
SET @SearchDecimal = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@SearchStr) = 1 THEN CONVERT(decimal(38,19), @SearchStr) ELSE NULL END
PRINT '@SearchStr2: ' + @SearchStr2
PRINT '@SearchDecimal: ' + CAST(@SearchDecimal AS nvarchar)

SET @TableName = ''
WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                    DATA_TYPE
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar',
                                  'int', 'bigint', 'tinyint', 'numeric', 'decimal')
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )
        SET @DataType =
        (
            SELECT DATA_TYPE
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) = @ColumnName
        )
        PRINT @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ' (' + @DataType + ')'

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            IF @DataType IN ('int', 'bigint', 'tinyint', 'numeric', 'decimal')
            BEGIN
                IF @SearchDecimal IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN
                    SET @Query = 'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS nvarchar(110)), 3630) ' +
                                 'FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                                 ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' = ' + CAST(@SearchDecimal AS nvarchar)
                    PRINT '    ' + @Query
                    INSERT INTO @Results
                    EXEC (@Query)
                END
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @Query = 'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) ' +
                             'FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                             ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                PRINT '    ' + @Query
                INSERT INTO @Results
                EXEC (@Query)
            END
        END
    END 
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM @Results
END
```

Answer (score 8):

I have a solution from a while ago that I kept improving. Also searches within XML columns if told to do so, or searches integer values if providing a integer only string.

```
/* Reto Egeter, fullparam.wordpress.com */

DECLARE @SearchStrTableName nvarchar(255), @SearchStrColumnName nvarchar(255), @SearchStrColumnValue nvarchar(255), @SearchStrInXML bit, @FullRowResult bit, @FullRowResultRows int
SET @SearchStrColumnValue = '%searchthis%' /* use LIKE syntax */
SET @FullRowResult = 1
SET @FullRowResultRows = 3
SET @SearchStrTableName = NULL /* NULL for all tables, uses LIKE syntax */
SET @SearchStrColumnName = NULL /* NULL for all columns, uses LIKE syntax */
SET @SearchStrInXML = 0 /* Searching XML data may be slow */

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results
CREATE TABLE #Results (TableName nvarchar(128), ColumnName nvarchar(128), ColumnValue nvarchar(max),ColumnType nvarchar(20))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256) = '',@ColumnName nvarchar(128),@ColumnType nvarchar(20), @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue nvarchar(110), @QuotedSearchStrColumnName nvarchar(110)
SET @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue = QUOTENAME(@SearchStrColumnValue,'''')
DECLARE @ColumnNameTable TABLE (COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(128),DATA_TYPE nvarchar(20))

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
SET @TableName =
(
SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND TABLE_NAME LIKE COALESCE(@SearchStrTableName,TABLE_NAME)
AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0
)
IF @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(''' + @TableName + ''', 2)
AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(''' + @TableName + ''', 1)
AND DATA_TYPE IN (' + CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@SearchStrColumnValue,'%',''),'_',''),'[',''),']',''),'-','')) = 1 THEN '''tinyint'',''int'',''smallint'',''bigint'',''numeric'',''decimal'',''smallmoney'',''money'',' ELSE '' END + '''char'',''varchar'',''nchar'',''nvarchar'',''timestamp'',''uniqueidentifier''' + CASE @SearchStrInXML WHEN 1 THEN ',''xml''' ELSE '' END + ')
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE COALESCE(' + CASE WHEN @SearchStrColumnName IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '''' + @SearchStrColumnName + '''' END + ',COLUMN_NAME)'
INSERT INTO @ColumnNameTable
EXEC (@sql)
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN_NAME FROM @ColumnNameTable)
BEGIN
PRINT @ColumnName
SELECT TOP 1 @ColumnName = COLUMN_NAME,@ColumnType = DATA_TYPE FROM @ColumnNameTable
SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''',''' + @ColumnName + ''',' + CASE @ColumnType WHEN 'xml' THEN 'LEFT(CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS nvarchar(MAX)), 4096),'''
WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr('+ @ColumnName + '),'''
ELSE 'LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 4096),''' END + @ColumnType + '''
FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
' WHERE ' + CASE @ColumnType WHEN 'xml' THEN 'CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS nvarchar(MAX))'
WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr('+ @ColumnName + ')'
ELSE @ColumnName END + ' LIKE ' + @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue
INSERT INTO #Results
EXEC(@sql)
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 IF @FullRowResult = 1
BEGIN
SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP ' + CAST(@FullRowResultRows AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' ''' + @TableName + ''' AS [TableFound],''' + @ColumnName + ''' AS [ColumnFound],''FullRow>'' AS [FullRow>],*' +
' FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
' WHERE ' + CASE @ColumnType WHEN 'xml' THEN 'CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS nvarchar(MAX))'
WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr('+ @ColumnName + ')'
ELSE @ColumnName END + ' LIKE ' + @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue
EXEC(@sql)
END
DELETE FROM @ColumnNameTable WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName
END 
END
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue, ColumnType, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM #Results
GROUP BY TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue, ColumnType
```

Source:
http://fullparam.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/fck-it-i-am-going-to-search-all-tables-all-collumns/

Comment: It was the only answer that worked with my privileges, searched not only strings and wasn't broken with my tables.

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me. The rest gave me an arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric. I suspect it is the large id numbers brought into SQL Server from Oracle going into results. Did not try to diagnose

Comment: Excellent solution for those with limited permissions!  But beware, this can take a **very** long time (hours in a large, complex database).  So have other things to work on while it cranks.  In some cases, it may be helpful to add a USE statement to limit the searched context.

Comment: between the one I tried this was the best in speed and accuracy

Answer (score 5):

It's my way to resolve this question. Tested on SQLServer2008R2

```
CREATE PROC SearchAllTables
@SearchStr nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @dml nvarchar(max) = N''        
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#Results
CREATE TABLE dbo.#Results
 ([tablename] nvarchar(100), 
  [ColumnName] nvarchar(100), 
  [Value] nvarchar(max))  
SELECT @dml += ' SELECT ''' + s.name + '.' + t.name + ''' AS [tablename], ''' + 
                c.name + ''' AS [ColumnName], CAST(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + 
               ' AS nvarchar(max)) AS [Value] FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) +
               ' (NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' AS nvarchar(max)) LIKE ' + '''%' + @SearchStr + '%'''
FROM sys.schemas s JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                   JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                   JOIN sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id AND c .user_type_id = ty .user_type_id
WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND ty.name NOT IN ('timestamp', 'image', 'sql_variant')

INSERT dbo.#Results
EXEC sp_executesql @dml

SELECT *
FROM dbo.#Results
END
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the really useful script.

You may need to add the following modification to the code if your tables have non-convertable fields:

```
SET @ColumnName =
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
            AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
            AND DATA_TYPE NOT IN ('text', 'image', 'ntext')                 
            AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
    )
```

Chris

Answer (score 3):

Here, very sweet and small solution:

```
1) create a store procedure:

create procedure get_table
@find_str varchar(50)
as 
begin
  declare @col_name varchar(500), @tab_name varchar(500);
  declare @find_tab TABLE(table_name varchar(100), column_name varchar(100));

  DECLARE tab_col cursor for 
  select C.name as 'col_name', T.name as tab_name
  from sys.tables as T
  left outer join sys.columns as C on  C.object_id=T.object_id
  left outer join sys.types as TP on  C.system_type_id=TP.system_type_id
  where type='U' 
  and TP.name in('text','ntext','varchar','char','nvarchar','nchar');

  open tab_col
  fetch next from tab_col into @col_name, @tab_name

  while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  begin        
    insert into @find_tab 
    exec('select ''' +  @tab_name + ''',''' + @col_name + ''' from ' + @tab_name + 
    ' where ' + @col_name + '=''' + @find_str + ''' group by ' + 
    @col_name + ' having count(*)>0');

    fetch next from tab_col into @col_name, @tab_name;
  end
  CLOSE tab_col;  
  DEALLOCATE tab_col; 
  select table_name, column_name from @find_tab;

end
```

==========================

```
2) call procedure by calling store procedure:
exec get_table 'serach_string';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have **phpMyAdmin** installed use its *Search* feature.

Select your DataBase.

Be sure you do have selected DataBase, not a table, otherwise you'll get a completely different search dialog.

1. Click *Search* tab
2. List item Choose the search term you want
3. Choose the tables to search

Answer (score 2):

Another way using JOIN and CURSOR:

```
USE My_Database;

-- Store results in a local temp table so that.  I'm using a
-- local temp table so that I can access it in SP_EXECUTESQL.
create table #tmp (
    tbl nvarchar(max),
    col nvarchar(max),
    val nvarchar(max)   
);

declare @tbl nvarchar(max);
declare @col nvarchar(max);
declare @q nvarchar(max);
declare @search nvarchar(max) = 'my search key';

-- Create a cursor on all columns in the database
declare c cursor for
SELECT tbls.TABLE_NAME, cols.COLUMN_NAME  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS tbls
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS cols
ON tbls.TABLE_NAME = cols.TABLE_NAME

-- For each table and column pair, see if the search value exists.
open c
fetch next from c into @tbl, @col
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    -- Look for the search key in current table column and if found add it to the results.
    SET @q = 'INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT ''' + @tbl + ''', ''' + @col + ''', ' + @col + ' FROM ' + @tbl + ' WHERE ' + @col + ' LIKE ''%' + @search + '%'''
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @q
    fetch next from c into @tbl, @col
end
close c
deallocate c

-- Get results
select * from #tmp

-- Remove local temp table.
drop table #tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- exec pSearchAllTables 'M54*'

ALTER PROC pSearchAllTables (@SearchStr NVARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    -- A procedure to search all tables in a database for a value
    -- Note: Use * or % for wildcard

    DECLARE 
        @Results TABLE([Schema.Table.ColumnName] NVARCHAR(370), ColumnValue NVARCHAR(3630))

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE 
        @TableName NVARCHAR(256) = ''
        , @ColumnName NVARCHAR(128)     
        , @SearchStr2 NVARCHAR(110) = QUOTENAME(REPLACE(@SearchStr, '*', '%'), '''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName = ''
            SET @TableName = 
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0
            )

            WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
                BEGIN
                    SET @ColumnName =
                    (
                        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                        AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                        AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                        AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
                    )

                    IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
                        BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO @Results 
                            EXEC ('SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2)

                        END

                END 

        END

    SELECT 
        [Schema.Table.ColumnName]
        , ColumnValue 
    FROM @Results
    GROUP BY 
        [Schema.Table.ColumnName]
        , ColumnValue 

END
```

Comment: I'm not clear how this works.  It looks like there are 2 search strings, or a search and replace string?  If I just want to search, where do I place the string I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to build an [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) for your database. It is assured to be pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

By far the best and most universal solution I found is to pipe a dump of the db through to a grep of what you are searching for.

e.g. for Mysql:

```
mysqldump -pPASSWORD database | grep 'search phrase'
```

Or if you get too many results, you can then output them to a file:

```
mysqldump -pPASSWORD database | grep 'search phrase' > results.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For Development purpose you can just export the required tables data into a single HTML and make a direct search on it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you want to get all the table with name a column name contain **logintime** in the database **MyDatabase** below is the code sample

```
    use MyDatabase

    SELECT t.name AS table_name,
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
    c.name AS column_name
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
    WHERE c.name LIKE '%logintime%'
    ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a just a numeric value = 6.84 - using the other answers here I was able to limit my search to this

```
Declare @sourceTable Table(id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, table_name varchar(1000), column_name varchar(1000))
Declare @resultsTable Table(id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, table_name varchar(1000))

Insert into @sourceTable(table_name, column_name)
select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.name as[table], c.name as column_name
from sys.columns c
join sys.tables t
on t.object_id = c.object_id
where type_name(user_type_id) in ('decimal', 'numeric', 'smallmoney', 'money', 'float', 'real')
order by[table], c.column_id;

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
Select table_name, column_name from @sourceTable
DECLARE @mytablename VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @mycolumnname VARCHAR(1000);

OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @mytablename, @mycolumnname

WHILE @ @FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    Insert into @ResultsTable(table_name)
    EXEC('SELECT ''' + @mytablename + '.' + @mycolumnname + '''  FROM ' + @mytablename + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
    ' WHERE ' + @mycolumnname + '=6.84')
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @mytablename, @mycolumnname  
END;
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
Select Distinct(table_name) from @ResultsTable
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of workable answers already. I just wanted to share one I wrote that has additional functionality.

```
--=======================================================================
--  MSSQL Unified Search
--  Minimum compatibility level = 130 (SQL Server 2016)
--      NOTE: The minimum compatibility level is required by the built-in STRING_SPLIT() function.
--          However, you can create the STRING_SPLIT() function at the bottom of this script for
--          lower versions of MSSQL Server.
--
--  Usage:
--      Set the parameters below and execute this script.
--
/************************ Enter Parameters Here ************************/
/**/
/**/    DECLARE @SearchString VARCHAR(1000) = 'string to search for';  -- Accepts SQL wilcards
/**/
/**/    DECLARE @IncludeUserTables BIT = 1;
/**/    DECLARE @IncludeViews BIT = 0;
/**/    DECLARE @IncludeStoredProcedures BIT = 0;
/**/    DECLARE @IncludeFunctions BIT = 0;
/**/    DECLARE @IncludeTriggers BIT = 0;
/**/
/**/    DECLARE @DebugMode BIT = 0;
/**/    DECLARE @ExcludeColumnTypes NVARCHAR(500) = 'text, ntext, char, nchar, timestamp, bigint, tinyint, smallint, bit, date, time, smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2, real, money, float, decimal, binary, varbinary, image';  -- Comma delimited list
/**/
/***********************************************************************/


SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @SearchString = QUOTENAME(@SearchString,'''');

DECLARE @Results TABLE ([ObjectType] NVARCHAR(200), [ObjectName] NVARCHAR(200), [ColumnName] NVARCHAR(400), [Value] NVARCHAR(MAX), [SelectStatement] NVARCHAR(1000));
DECLARE @ExcludeColTypes TABLE (system_type_id INT);

INSERT INTO @ExcludeColTypes ([system_type_id])
    SELECT [system_type_id]
    FROM sys.types WHERE
    [name] IN (
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM([value])) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ExcludeColumnTypes,',')
        );

DECLARE @ObjectType NVARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @ObjectName NVARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SelectStatement NVARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(4000);


/********************* Table Objects *********************/
IF (@IncludeUserTables = 1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TableObjectId INT = (SELECT MIN([object_id]) FROM sys.tables);
    DECLARE @ColumnId INT;
    WHILE @TableObjectId IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    
        SELECT @ObjectType = 'USER TABLE';
        SELECT @ObjectName = '[' + SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]) + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(@TableObjectId) + ']' FROM sys.tables WHERE [object_id] = @TableObjectId;

        SET @ColumnId = (SELECT MIN([column_id]) FROM sys.columns WHERE [system_type_id] NOT IN (SELECT [system_type_id] FROM @ExcludeColTypes) AND [object_id] = @TableObjectId);
        WHILE @ColumnId IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN

            SELECT @Value = '[' + [name] +']' FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = @TableObjectId AND column_id = @ColumnId;

            SET @SelectStatement = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @ObjectName + ' WHERE CAST(' + @Value + ' AS NVARCHAR(4000)) LIKE ' + @SearchString + ';';

            SET @Query = 'SELECT '
                + QUOTENAME(@ObjectType, '''')
                + ', ' + QUOTENAME(@ObjectName, '''')
                + ', ' + QUOTENAME(@Value, '''')
                + ', ' + @Value
                + ', ''' + REPLACE(@SelectStatement,'''','''''') + ''''
                + ' FROM ' + @ObjectName
                + ' WHERE CAST(' + @Value + ' AS NVARCHAR(4000)) LIKE ' + @SearchString + ';';

            IF @DebugMode = 0
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @Results EXEC(@Query);
            END;
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'Select Statement:  ' + @SelectStatement;
                PRINT 'Query:  ' + @Query;
            END;

            SET @ColumnId = (SELECT MIN([column_id]) FROM sys.columns WHERE [system_type_id] NOT IN (SELECT [system_type_id] FROM @ExcludeColTypes) AND [object_id] = @TableObjectId AND [column_id] > @ColumnId);
        END;

        SET @TableObjectId = (SELECT MIN([object_id]) FROM sys.tables WHERE [object_id] > @TableObjectId);
    END;
END;

/********************* Objects Other than Tables *********************/
SET @Query = 'SELECT ' +
    'ObjectType = CASE ' +
        'WHEN b.[type] = ''V'' THEN ''VIEW'' ' +
        'WHEN b.[type] = ''P'' THEN ''STORED PROCEDURE'' ' +
        'WHEN b.[type] = ''FN'' THEN ''SCALAR-VALUED FUNCTION'' ' +
        'WHEN b.[type] = ''IF'' THEN ''TABLE-VALUED FUNCTION'' ' +
        'WHEN b.[type] = ''TR'' THEN ''TRIGGER'' ' +
    'END ' +
    ',[ObjectName] = ''['' + SCHEMA_NAME(b.[schema_id]) + ''].['' + OBJECT_NAME(a.[object_id]) + '']'' ' +
    ',[ColumnName] = NULL ' +
    ',[Value] = a.[definition] ' +
    ',[SelectStatement] = ''SP_HELPTEXT '' + QUOTENAME(''['' + SCHEMA_NAME(b.[schema_id]) + ''].['' + OBJECT_NAME(a.[object_id]) + '']'','''''''') + '';'' ' +
'FROM [sys].[sql_modules] a ' +
'JOIN [sys].[objects] b ON a.[object_id] = b.[object_id] ' +
'WHERE ' +
    '( ' +
    '   a.[definition] LIKE ' + @SearchString + 
    ') ' +
    'AND ' +
    '( ' +
    '   ( ' +
            CAST(@IncludeViews AS VARCHAR(1)) + ' = 1 ' +
    '       AND ' +
    '       b.[type] IN (''V'') ' +
    '   ) ' +
    '   OR ' +
    '   ( ' +
            CAST(@IncludeStoredProcedures AS VARCHAR(1)) + ' = 1 ' +
    '       AND ' +
    '       b.[type] IN (''P'') ' +
    '   ) ' +
    '   OR ' +
    '   ( ' +
            CAST(@IncludeFunctions AS VARCHAR(1)) + ' = 1 ' +
    '       AND ' +
    '       b.[type] IN (''FN'',''IF'') ' +
    '   ) ' +
    '   OR ' +
    '   ( ' +
            CAST(@IncludeTriggers AS VARCHAR(1)) + ' = 1 ' +
    '       AND ' +
    '       b.[type] IN (''TR'') ' +
    '   ) ' +
    '); ';

IF @DebugMode = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Results EXEC(@Query);
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Select Statement:  ' + @SelectStatement;
    PRINT 'Query:  ' + @Query;
END;

IF @DebugMode = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        [ObjectType]
        ,[ObjectName]
        ,[ColumnName]
        ,[Value]
        ,[Count] = CASE
            WHEN [ObjectType] IN ('USER TABLE') THEN COUNT(1)
            ELSE NULL
        END
        ,[SelectStatement]
    FROM @Results
    GROUP BY [ObjectType], [ObjectName], [ColumnName], [Value], [SelectStatement]
    ORDER BY [Value];
END;

/********************** STRING_SPLIT() FUNCTION **********************
CREATE FUNCTION STRING_SPLIT (
    @Expression nvarchar(4000)
    ,@Delimiter nvarchar(100)
)
RETURNS @Ret TABLE ([value] NVARCHAR(4000))
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Start INT = 0, @End INT, @Length INT;
    SELECT @End = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@Expression), @Length = @End - @Start;

    IF @End <= 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Ret ([value]) VALUES (@Expression);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        WHILE @Length >= 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Ret ([value])
                SELECT ltrim(rtrim(substring(@Expression,@Start,@Length)));
    
            SELECT @Start = @End + LEN(@Delimiter)
            SELECT @End = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@Expression,@Start)
            IF @End < 1
                SELECT @End = LEN(@Expression) + 1;
            SELECT @Length = @End - @Start;
    
        END;
    END;
    RETURN;
END;
*********************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked [Tim Gaunt's solution](https://tsd.digital/blog/search-every-table-and-field-in-a-sql-server-database-updated/) (which is itself an updated version of the accepted answer) to run on Azure Synapse SQL with its limitations (INSERT...EXEC syntax does not work), as well as a few other minor changes I needed:

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100) = '%myvalue%'
DECLARE @SchemaName nvarchar(100) = NULL -- Specify a schema name, or NULL to search all tables in all schemas

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AllResults') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #AllResults
END
CREATE TABLE #AllResults (TableName nvarchar(256), ColumnName nvarchar(128), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128)
SET  @TableName = ''

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    (@SchemaName IS NULL OR @SchemaName = TABLE_SCHEMA)
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                            ), 'IsMSShipped'
                            ) = 0
    )

    PRINT 'Searching ' + @TableName + '...'

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN

        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal', 'bigint')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )
    
        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000) = 
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''' AS [TableName],''' + @ColumnName + ''' AS [ColumnName], CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS NVARCHAR(3630)) AS [ColumnValue] INTO #Results FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ''' + @SearchStr + ''''

            PRINT @query

            EXEC (@query)

            INSERT INTO #AllResults SELECT * FROM #Results

            DROP TABLE #Results

        END
    END    
END

SELECT TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue, [Count of occurences] = COUNT(*), [Query] = 'SELECT * FROM ' + TableName + ' WHERE ' + ColumnName + ' LIKE ''' + @SearchStr + ''''
FROM #AllResults 
GROUP BY TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue 
ORDER BY TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue
```