# Find a string in a specific table

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm working with a oracle database, I'm wondering if there is a way to find all rows that contains a value in any column. For example let's consider this table:

```
               Weather

city          state        high    low

Phoenix       Arizona      105     90

Tucson        Arizona      101     92

Flagstaff     Arizona      88      69

San Diego     California   77      60

Albuquerque   New Mexico   80      72
```

Basically (I know it's not possible), but I would like to do something like this:

```
Select * From Weather Where * LIKE '%f%'
```

and it would give me the rows

```
Flagstaff     Arizona      88      69
San Diego     California   77      60
```

I could do it on the Java side, by querying all the rows then with the ResultSet dynamically search for a given value in a column and add that row. The problem is that some table contains millions of rows and I guess it would be more efficient do it on the database side, so I only fetch wanted rows from the network.

Is it possible to do it on the SQL side directly?

Comment: So column and value both are user inputs?

Comment: @AniketThakur No only the value, otherwise it's just a simple sql query with a where clause

Comment: You need to know which table user is trying to query. That way you could get all of it's columns in a function and then build a query with `where` condition on every column.

Comment: If you are not sure about the column name in advance, then obviously you cannot have a static query. So, the only possible way is to (ab)use dynamic SQL in PL/SQL.

Comment: you may refer to this :[ MS-SQL][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709120/how-to-search-for-one-value-in-any-column-of-any-table-inside-one-ms-sql-databas

Comment: Don't get me started on performance this query will have...

Comment: @ConsiderMe Actually performance doesn't really matter at first, the only consideration is to fetch only interesting rows (so to not transfer useless data over the network)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use view `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` to search all columns in given table:

```
DECLARE
  v_table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'dual';
  v_search_string VARCHAR2(100) := 'X';
  v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
  c_result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  v_sql := 'SELECT * FROM ' || v_table_name || ' WHERE 1=1';
  FOR r_c IN (SELECT column_name
              FROM all_tab_columns
              WHERE table_name = v_table_name) LOOP
    v_sql := v_sql || ' OR ' || r_c.column_name || ' LIKE ''%' || v_search_string || '%''';
  END LOOP;
  OPEN c_result FOR v_sql;
END;
/
```

In this case you can write this as procedure and return cursor to JAVA to fetch data.

Only - all time you will face table FULL scans. But if you look at data transfer then this solution will be better than to do all search in JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do it on the SQL side directly?

**No**. It is not possible in **pure SQL** since you need to know the column names in advance, i.e. they must be **static**.

The only possible way to build the query **dynamically** is to (ab)use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in **PL/SQL**.

Though, I would say it is not a good design. The application must know which objects to access in advance.

Anyway, in PL/SQL you could do something like:

```
v_sql = q'[SELECT ... FROM table_name WHERE ]';
v_sql:= v_sql || column_name1 || ' LIKE ''%f''' || ' OR '|| column_name2 || 'LIKE ''%f''';
```

And then, use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** to execute the dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read thru "Text Application Developer's Guide"
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm#g1016054

May be you can concatenate all your data column and update in one more addition column in the same table, then use text search to get the result.