# How do I check if there are any NULLs in an entire table (across all columns) in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, null

I'm wondering if I can run an ad-hoc query just to see if a table contains any NULL values across any of its columns. The table has 100+ columns so doing this manually would be a huge pain.

Comment: Do all (or at least most) 100+ columns *allow* NULL values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search for one value in any column of any table inside one MS-SQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709120/how-to-search-for-one-value-in-any-column-of-any-table-inside-one-ms-sql-databas)

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this:

```
DECLARE @tb NVARCHAR(255) = N'dbo.[table]';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @tb
    + ' WHERE 1 = 0';

SELECT @sql += N' OR ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' IS NULL'
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tb);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

[Source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14864/test-if-any-fields-are-null)