# Return Column and Table holding value

Tags: mysql, sql

I can write a query to search for a table that has a particular column in a DB

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%A'
```

but My Question is:

can I search an entire DB for a value in a column?
So I'm unsure the name of the column and I am unsure the name of the DB table but I know the value is 'Active'

Comment: take a look at this question, is SQL Server, but can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709120/how-to-search-for-one-value-in-any-column-of-any-table-inside-one-ms-sql-databas

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. In that case, you need to prepare dynamic query once you get list of tables, which consists column, which actually you are looking for.

Now create a cursor for

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%A'
```

Using above cursor loop below

```
SET @s = CONCAT("select count(*) from [tablename] where [columnname] like ","'%SOMETHING%'");
PREPARE stmt FROM @s
execute stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```