# Search all tables in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: ssms

Is there any way to search all the tables in a database for the value 111221112522? I'm not sure what column, let alone table or maybe even what database this value is in.

I tried using the filter functionality but to no avail.

Comment: Asked and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796506/search-all-tables-all-columns-for-a-specific-value-sql-server  THis does assume you're using MSSMS to connect to a Microsoft SQL database.

Comment: See my [answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709120/search-for-one-value-in-any-column-of-any-table-inside-a-database/75970816#75970816) it will probably do exactly what you want.