# Locate Table and Column name by Integer Id Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I support a legacy application that has probably over a thousand tables with tons of columns in each row.

To make things even more fun, the names are not consistent across Foreign keys. I have a unique integer identifier (`Id: 1132044502`) that I need to find somewhere in this SQL Server DB.

Is there a way to locate the table and columns just by that ID?

I can't use Stored Procedures within the system so it has to run ad-hoc.

Some of the scripts I found that work for strings I don't know how to convert to just work and look for integer columns.

Comment: Do you have foreign key relationships defined? Have you looked in `sys.columns`?

Comment: Not Really... column names are usually names 'ND101' or 'FL573' These are both foreign keys to other areas within NSLDS Federal data that gets returned and stored in this db. Its a horrible legacy application from the 70's and has changed hands so many times nobody knows where anything is or how it runs lol. Only true thing I have to go off of for an issue is the Id of this record.

Comment: Can you get a list of tables and columns through which you want to search? If so, you could dynamically search through them. Might not be pretty, but should work

Comment: So you want to find which table has that specific value in a column? I wrote a utility to do that and shared it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709120/search-for-one-value-in-any-column-of-any-table-inside-a-database/75970816#75970816) - however it may not function on sql server 2012

Comment: @Stu Exactly! Any column on any table is possible. That utility looks good but It's a SP which I won't have access to create or run (really locked down on our environment due to security). All I can really do is SQL selects into temp tables to try and locate what table and from there figure out where to delete it in the front end. Of course every step of this is as complicated as humanly possible lol.

Comment: it's easy to rewrite the procedure to be non-proc, just remove create procedure name part and declare the parameters

Comment: is your column of type INT, or you don't know the type?

Comment: @siggemannen It's definitely a column type of Int that I am searching for, will give it a try converting just asking to see if anybody has anything off-hand for this type of search (also asking for anybody in the future with the same issue).