# searching data from multiple database

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Good Afternoon in GMT +8

is there a way to search for a data from multiple databases? uhm, i know that we could do
something like below:

`select * from table1 where [name] = 'John'`

`select * from table2 where [name] = 'John'`

is there a way to search for it like

`select * from sometables where [name] = 'john'`

Comment: After seeing example I think your questing is searching data from multiple tables.if so I would prefer using join.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/how-do-i-find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-sql-server-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
  SELECT * FROM [DataBaseName].[Schema].[Table] WHERE [Your Condition]
```

You can also use such queries in Join's e.g You have two `DataBases`

```
DataBase1: 
DataBase Name : MyDB1
Table Name : Table1
DataBase2:
DataBase Name : MyDB2
Table Name : Table1
```

**Note: Both tables have same structure like `(Id, Name, FatherName, Address)`**

Your query will be ..

```
SELECT      *
FROM        MyDB1.dbo.Table1 a
INNER JOIN  MyDB2.dbo.Table1 b
ON          a.Id = b.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup Linked server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx
After then you would be able to call database on other server

select
    *
from
    LocalTable,
    [OtherServerName].[OtherDB].[dbo].[OtherTable]