# Search whole database instead of single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

I want to find a number or string in a very large database. Is there any way to make an SQL Query that searches the entire database, and not just a single table?

I'm looking for something like:

```
select * from *;
```

Comment: Heidisql has the ability to search an entire databse,probably other clients as well.

Comment: apex sql tools has a feature that does this http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx

Comment: What is the database platform?  MySQL, SQL Server, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server this post from kd7 might be what you're looking for:
[How do I find a value anywhere in a SQL Server Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/how-do-i-find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-sql-server-database?answertab=votes#tab-top)