# SQL search all columns of a table for text value

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, select, text

I have a huge table with many columns and I know that this columns sometimes takes some specific value 'MyValue'. How can I select all the rows in that one specific table containing 'MyValue' regardless in which column.

I found related topic here:
[How do I find a value anywhere in a SQL Server Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/how-do-i-find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-sql-server-database)

But my query needs a smaller cannon. I know the table name, it is, let's say 'MyTable'. I do not need to search the whole db.

Comment: Do you mean (1) all rows from the table, which has at least one row containing MyValue, or (2) just the rows containing MyValue?

Comment: @jarlh I want to select all the rows containing 'john' no matter if 'john' is in FirstName column or LastName column or WhatEverOther coulmn. 'john' has to be in at least one column.

Comment: I think this is bad DB design/idea.

Comment: Are you also using SQL Server or a different DBMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it without a special procedure in a simple statement, you could convert each row to XML and then use an XQuery on the XML to search for any value in the row that matches.  So for example:

```
declare @SearchValue as varchar(20)
set @SearchValue = 'MyValue'

select *
    --,(select MyTable.* for XML PATH (''),TYPE) AllColumns
    --,convert(nvarchar(255),(select MyTable.* for XML PATH (''),TYPE).query('for $item in * where $item=sql:variable("@SearchValue") return $item')) FoundColumns
from MyTable
where convert(nvarchar(255),(select MyTable.* for XML PATH (''),TYPE).query('for $item in * where $item=sql:variable("@SearchValue") return $item'))<>''
```

A procedure specifically designed for this task could probably do this more efficiently and could take advantage of indexes... etc.  Honestly I would not put this into a production database solution without quite a bit of consideration, but as a throw together search tool it's not bad.  I ran a search on a 700,000 record table in 40 seconds.  However if I filter by each column individually it runs nearly instantly.  Also a few more caveats:

- None of the table columns can not have spaces or other unfriendly
  characters for an XML tag.  I couldn't figure out how to get column names with spaces to work.  Maybe there's a way.
- The filter has to be written in XQuery... which is not exactly like
  SQL.  But you can use =, <, >, and there's even pattern matching.
- The parameter for the query function must be a string literal.  So
  you can't build a string dynamically.  This is why I used the variable for your search values, but you could also use a sql:column("ColName") if needed.
- If searching for other types besides strings, the search string you use must match exactly what the field would be converted to as an XML value.

Comment: Thanks. This is clever to convert it to XML

Comment: this is sql server related query ?

Comment: Yes, The XML data type and methods can be used in SQL Server 2005 and up.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by reversing the value and column in `In` operator.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Mytable
WHERE  'Myvalue' IN ( Col1, Col2, col3,.... )
```

If you don't want to type the columns, then pull it from `information_schema.column` view and create a `dynamic query`

Comment: "Containing", I guess LIKE is needed. Not really an ideal solution for most dbms...

Comment: @jarlh - am not sure about what he is trying mean by saying `containing`. But he/she is looking for a solution in `Sql Server`

Comment: @Przemyslaw Remin consider making this the accepted answer - probably the cleanest way

Answer (score 4):

You can concatenate all columns with `+` and then perform a `LIKE` search:

```
SELECT *
FROM   data
WHERE  col1 + '#' + col2 + '#' + col3 like '%test%'
```

Adding a separator (I use `#`) between the columns ensures you won't get false positives from the concatenation, e.g. if col2 = 'te' and col3 = 'st'

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/871ce/4)