# SQL Server 2008 find and replace

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server database called `school`. I just want to find a string called `www.yahoo.com` and replace with `www.google.com`.

I have the find and replace do in whole database anyone can put a example of code of SQL query to do that?

Comment: Meaning you have to search every single column in every single row in every single table? There is no simple way to do this. And there is no fast way to do this either.

Comment: Is the database normalized, so that the searched string is in a specific table?

Comment: Is the search string the sole content of a table column "some where in one of your tables" or could it even be part of a bigger (surrounding) text?

Comment: See [How do I find a value anywhere in a SQL Server Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/436351/4275342)

Comment: This didn't help you?   It came up as the first result when I googled:   https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1555/sql-server-find-and-replace-values-in-all-tables-and-all-text-columns/

Comment: I think the last link is what I need I'll test.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query on a particular column in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE school
SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name,'www.yahoo.com','www.google.com')
WHERE column_name LIKE '%www.yahoo.com%'
```