# Is there any way to find a specific value in every field of every table in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to find a specific value in every field of every table in Microsoft SQL Server?

For example I wish to find any record with '666333222' in it...is it possible?

Comment: please clarify your question,with some sample data and explain along with it and post an expected result,also please tag the relevant RDBMS

Comment: Yes it is. For example Mysql has information_schema database so you can build a query. I have done it several times. You need to clarify which RMBMS are you using and what have you tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find a value anywhere in a SQL Server Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/how-do-i-find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-sql-server-database)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @TheGameiswar for example I want to entirely delete an Item with a specific ID. I want to find out exactly which tables include this ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following stored procedure to search every field of every table
for a specific value:

```
CREATE PROC sp_SearchAllTables
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END    
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
END
```

and then use it like this:

```
exec sp_SearchAllTables 'your search text here';
```

Answer (score 0):

For mysql you can get all table names by :

Select your database by 'use' statement then use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

Then you can use Java to loop through each table.E.g.

[Simple java program to access a table](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/connecting_to_a_database_table.html)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Full text search of SQL Server for the tables and you will be easily be able to query specific content in the columns.

[Read Full Text Search on SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search)

[Installing Full Text Search on SQL Server 2017](https://sqlcontent.com/index.php/2018/04/04/installing-full-text-search-with-sql-2017/)