# How to do a truly global search (across ALL ENTITIES) for a value in DynamicsCRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to work out how to search for a value in DynamicsCRM that could be sitting in any hundreds of possible entities.

The standard 'global search' function is hopelessly inadequate for this task, as it limits the number of entities that can be searched at a time to 10 (That method is [described here](http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2015/03/customizing-global-search-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2015/)).

This is for an online (ie, NOT on-premises) CRM instance. It's a one off search that we'd like a Sys Admin to be able to do.

Help?

Thanks.

Comment: On-premise or Online? Is this a one-time search or ongoing requirement? Is this something an admin is doing or do you need end-users to run this search?

Comment: Online. It's a one time. Only the CRM Admin should be able to do it. (I will edit the original Q).

Answer (score 1):

Since it is online you don't have a lot of options. I would request a copy of your CRM database via Microsoft Support. Mount it in SQL Server - if you don't have a local instance of SQL Server create a SQL Server VM in Azure. Then use this answer to search across the database: https://stackoverflow.com/a/436382/394978.

The only alternative is to write a bunch of code to execute the search. The results will be the same but you have to write the code and depending on the size of your CRM database it could be hours to days to search everything.