# Find value of row by search entire database ( all tables and all columns) SQL

Tags: sql

I want to find the value of a row for my entire database. I don't know what column or table it would be in. I have been trying to find an answer on stackoverflow but cant find anything....

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: So you want to search every column of every table for a specific value? Say, 'dog' and it returns a list of tables/columns that contain 'dog'? If so, the answer will be database specific.

Comment: Yeah that would work. I don't mind if its database specific. 
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find a value anywhere in a SQL Server Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/how-do-i-find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-sql-server-database)

Comment: *Why* do you need to search in all columns/tables? You're working in a DBMS, not an Excel sheet.

Comment: @dnoeth - I once worked on a billing system and I saw some very useful textual information in the application that I just couldn't find in the database. A one-time brute force search seemed like a reasonable solution at that time.