# Incorrect Syntax near special character ✉

Tags: sql, sql-server, frameworks

I'm using a code generator framework and when trying to update a registry I get the following syntax error

```
Incorrect syntax near '✉'
```

[image: Here's a capture of that error that was sent to me]

I think there's a field with that special character.

How can I find that character in all the tables to view if that is what is causing the problem?

Comment: Where is the code that raise this error?

Comment: Searching every column of every table has been asked and answered around here a lot. Here is one of them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/how-do-i-find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-sql-server-database

Answer (score 1):

There a good function that I found a long time ago and I use it constantly, it finds all the invisible/ weird characters, Try it maybe it will work in your case as well. The way you would do it is, Select dbo.ShowWhiteSpace(Column name)
That's of course if you know the table that has this issue

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ShowWhiteSpace] (@str varchar(8000))
RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @ShowWhiteSpace varchar(8000);
     SET @ShowWhiteSpace = @str
     SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(32), 'Char(32),[?]')
     SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(13), '[CR]')
     SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(10), '[LF]')
     SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(9),  '[TAB]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(1),  '[SOH]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(2),  '[STX]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(3),  '[ETX]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(4),  '[EOT]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(5),  '[ENQ]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(6),  '[ACK]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(7),  '[BEL]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(8),  '[BS]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(11), '[VT]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(12), '[FF]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(14), '[SO]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(15), '[SI]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(16), '[DLE]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(17), '[DC1]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(18), '[DC2]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(19), '[DC3]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(20), '[DC4]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(21), '[NAK]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(22), '[SYN]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(23), '[ETB]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(24), '[CAN]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(25), '[EM]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(26), '[SUB]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(27), '[ESC]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(28), '[FS]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(29), '[GS]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(30), '[RS]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(31), '[US]')
     RETURN(@ShowWhiteSpace)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for unicode    9993, which is the envelope symbol in decimal format (there's also hex).
https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%E2%9C%89

Depending on what database you're using (oracle vs sqlserver vs something else), your methods for finding that particular unicode character will vary.