# Search any property of an anonymous type for a given string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, anonymous-types

**End Result**

I need to be able to search any database table for all rows that contain the given search string somewhere in any of the columns.

**Current Implementation**

I'm using anonymous types to handle the case when an anonymous `select` lambda statement is used.  Currently, using reflection, I can loop through the `PropertyInfo[]` of the given anonymous type, get the values one by one and compare them to my search string.

```
var type = ob.GetType();
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
{

    var val = prop.GetValue(ob, null);
    if (val.ToString().Contains(search)) return true;
}
```

**The Problem**

This implementation works great for anonymous lists.  However, when using `IQueryables` that map to SQL via EntityFramework, it doesn't because lambda expressions cannot build SQL queries that use c# in the query.  The only path I've been able to find so far is creating a complex Expression tree to mimic the `foreach` loop required to loop through and test all of the `PropertyInfo` items associated with the anonymous object.

Is there a another way to do this or am I going to have to dig through some Expression tree articles?

Comment: Have you considered using SQL Server's Full Text Search?

Comment: You can create stored procedure that will do the search in everywhere: https://stackoverflow.com/a/436382/1225270 and use that stored procedure to do the search in your code.

Comment: Thank you both.  I will take a look at those.  However, I was hoping there was a way to do this code-first using lambdas.  I have very little experience running straight SQL scripts from within c# methods