# Searching for objects database-wide thru INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add another column having a COUNT() subquery using the table and column names from TBL_A.TABLE_NAME and TBL_A.COLUMN_NAME respectively but the subquery does not accept the value from TBL_A.TABLE_NAME as a valid table object.

Currently using MS SQL server

```
SELECT TBL_A.TABLE_NAME
     , TBL_A.COLUMN_NAME
     , TBL_A.DATA_TYPE
     , (SELECT [TBL_A].[COLUMN_NAME] FROM [TBL_A].[TABLE_NAME] WHERE [TBL_A].[COLUMN_NAME] = 'Some Keyword')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS TBL_A;
```

I want to check if the keyword I entered is present in the specified tablename.columnname in INFORMATION_SCHEMA (e.g. COUNT > 0 thus is PRESENT)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Skip the sub-query, do a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: @Nifriz - Using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @jarlh - my database has dozen thousands of rows in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. I cannot possibly LEFT JOIN all those tables.
  I want to use the values from TBL_A.TABLE_NAME and TBL_A.COLUMN_NAME as the table name and column name for the COUNT() sub-query. Please correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: Seems like you need to re-design your database.

Comment: What you are looking for is a little big more compex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-database

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.
**Note:** It is supported in SQL Server (starting with 2008).

It uses a **[SELECT - OVER Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** and searches for Columns containing the desired keyword.

```
SELECT [TBL_A].[TABLE_SCHEMA]  
    , TBL_A.TABLE_NAME  
    , TBL_A.COLUMN_NAME  
    , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [TBL_A].[TABLE_SCHEMA], [TBL_A].[TABLE_NAME])  
        AS [Count in Current Table]  
    , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [TBL_A].[COLUMN_NAME])  
        AS [Count in Current Database]  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS TBL_A  
WHERE [TBL_A].[COLUMN_NAME] LIKE '%Some Keyword%';
```