# Find a value anywhere in a Vertica database

Tags: sql, vertica

Is there a way to search all columns of all tables in a given database for a specific value (numeric or string) in **Vertica**?

This question is inspired by [Find a value anywhere in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-database) for SQL Server.

Comment: SQL stands for Structured Query Language. What you're asking for is for Unstructured data queries. No matter how you do this, performance is going to suck, so why do you need this, especially in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful what you wish for.

This one took 13 minutes to run only in my small database, in the public schema.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.findstring (
  IN searcharg   VARCHAR -- search argument
, IN _tbschema   VARCHAR -- schema name - empty string if all schemas
) LANGUAGE PLvSQL SECURITY INVOKER AS $$
DECLARE
  tbschema VARCHAR(128);
  tbname   VARCHAR(128);
  colname  VARCHAR(128);
  sq       VARCHAR(65000);
  rowsfound INT;
BEGIN
  IF _tbschema = '' THEN
     _tbschema = '%';
  END IF; 
  FOR tbschema, tbname, colname IN QUERY 
    SELECT c.table_schema,c.table_name,column_name FROM columns c JOIN tables t USING(table_id)
    WHERE data_type_id < 17 -- avoid non-castable data types
      AND NOT c.is_system_table
      AND table_definition = '' -- not an external table
      AND c.table_schema ~~* _tbschema
    ORDER BY 1,2,ordinal_position
  LOOP
    sq:='SELECT COUNT(*) as rowsfound FROM '||QUOTE_IDENT(tbschema)||'.'||QUOTE_IDENT(tbname)||
       ' WHERE '||QUOTE_IDENT(colname)||'::VARCHAR='||QUOTE_LITERAL(searcharg);
    rowsfound := EXECUTE sq; 
    IF rowsfound > 0 THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'found % instances in %.%.%',rowsfound,tbschema,tbname,colname;
    END IF; 
   END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CALL findstring('42','public');                                                                                                                                                                                

01000:1:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 1 instances in public.at1.id
01000:2:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 79 instances in public.ate.id
01000:3:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 8600225 instances in public.ate.ix
01000:4:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 791 instances in public.ate.ae
01000:5:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 79 instances in public.ati.id
01000:6:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 8600225 instances in public.ati.ix
01000:7:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 791 instances in public.ati.ae
01000:8:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 158 instances in public.att.id
01000:9:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 52479 instances in public.att.ix
01000:10:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 3 instances in public.att.ae
01000:11:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 5 instances in public.prod_dim.product_key
01000:12:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 597 instances in public.prod_dim.weight
01000:13:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 19 instances in public.prod_dim.product_price
01000:14:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 193 instances in public.prod_dim.product_cost
01000:15:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 22 instances in public.prod_dim.lowest_competitor_price
01000:16:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 16 instances in public.prod_dim.highest_competitor_price
01000:17:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 28 instances in public.prod_dim.average_competitor_price
01000:18:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 5 instances in public.product_dimension.product_key
01000:19:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 597 instances in public.product_dimension.weight
01000:20:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 19 instances in public.product_dimension.product_price
01000:21:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 193 instances in public.product_dimension.product_cost
01000:22:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 22 instances in public.product_dimension.lowest_competitor_price
01000:23:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 16 instances in public.product_dimension.highest_competitor_price
01000:24:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 28 instances in public.product_dimension.average_competitor_price
01000:25:2005:NOTICE 2005:  found 1 instances in public.ttest.c_int
findstring
         0
call succeeded; 1 row fetched
Timing:|_tm_prepare  |_tm_execute  |_tm_cmd_total|_tm_fetch_1st|_tm_fetch_tot                                                                                                                                  
Timing:| 00:00:00.016| 00:13:11.408| 00:13:11.425| 00:00:00.000| 00:00:00.000
```