# Find a value anywhere in a database with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have find this similar question in this post
([Find a value anywhere in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-database))

But when I try it in database that using PostgreSQL server,
It do not work

How can I have this similar query using PostgreSQL server
I am using DBeaver to execute the query

So far, I have this query to get the table, search with table_name or column_name

```
select table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, column_name
from information_schema.columns
where 1 = 1
--and table_schema  = 'ws_go_daa'
and table_name like '%prism%'
--and column_name like '%itm%'
and column_name  like '%po%'
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path looking into [`information_schema.columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html). You can get all schema, table and column names there and [iterate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) over them, searching for your value using [dynamic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) statements. [Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8ZJ1CG0H):

```
create table some_table as select 'some_specific_text_value'::text as some_text_column;
create table another_table as select '1234567890'::int as some_int_column;

create function find_anywhere(
  target_value anyelement, 
  is_type_strict boolean default true,
  is_searching_catalogs boolean default false) 
returns table (table_schema text, table_name text, column_name text, r record)
language plpgsql as $f$
begin
  for table_schema, table_name, column_name in
     select i.table_schema,i.table_name,i.column_name,i.data_type
     from information_schema.columns i
     where (not is_type_strict 
            or i.data_type::text=pg_typeof(target_value)::text)
     and (is_searching_catalogs 
          or i.table_schema not in ('pg_catalog','information_schema'))
  loop
     for r in execute format($q$ select r from %1$I.%2$I r 
                                 where case when $2 
                                 then r.%3$I is not distinct from $1
                                 else r.%3$I::text is not distinct from $1::text
                                 end
                             $q$
                             ,table_schema, table_name, column_name)
              using target_value, is_type_strict
     loop
        return next;
     end loop;
  end loop;
end $f$;

select * from find_anywhere('some_specific_text_value'::text);
```

| table_schema | table_name | column_name | r |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| public | some_table | some_text_column | ("(some_specific_text_value)") |

```sql
select * from find_anywhere(1234567890::int);
```

| table_schema | table_name | column_name | r |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| public | another_table | some_int_column | ("(1234567890)") |

The reason to return the whole matching record is to be able to later pinpoint the row. An alternative would be to look up non-partial unique indexes in [`pg_index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-index.html) and only return a minimal set of columns that uniquely identify the row.

Non-strict version could also get away with a single unnested loop by running one `target_value::text in (col1::text,col2::text...)` instead of checking column-by-column. While this would still give you the match, it wouldn't specify the matching column.

All types are coercible to `text`, so the entire `strict` logic could be removed. I think it's worth keeping for performance: looking for `'2023-11-08'::date` won't have to checking all `text` in the database. It could be improved to try and compare similar types, also checking `timestamp`s whenever you look for a `date` and vice versa.

---

You might want to overload it to avoid having to cast explicitly:

```
select * from find_anywhere('some_specific_text_value');
```

> ```
> ERROR:  could not determine polymorphic type because input has type unknown
> ```

```
create function find_anywhere(target_value text) 
  returns table (table_schema text, table_name text, column_name text, r record)
language sql as $f$ select find_anywhere($1::text,true,false) $f$;

select * from find_anywhere('some_specific_text_value');
```

| table_schema | table_name | column_name | r |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| public | some_table | some_text_column | ("(some_specific_text_value)") |